# Debian prompt takes variables in PS1 literally

Tags: bash

I have a small problem with the prompt on a debian server, I keep getting the variables as literals:

```
    PS1='\u \w $'
```

gives me a prompt showing:

```
    \u \w $
```

where it should imho show:

```
    username dirname $
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try using double quotes instead of single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your shell is bash ? With other shells (such as dash), such variables may not work.

Comment: My bad, the shell is sh instead of bash.